# The random incidence paradox of sampling problem

Tags: probability

There are 100 families: 10 families have no children, 40 families have 1 child each, 30 families have 2 children each, 10 families have 3 each, and 10 families have 4 each.

If you pick a family at random, the expected number of children in that family is $1.7$. If you pick a child at random, the expected number of children in that child's family is $2.41$.

Suppose that a fraction $p_k$ of the families have $k$ children each. Let $K$ be the number of children in a randomly selected family, and let $a=E[K]$ and $b=E[K^2]$. Let $W$ be the number of children in a randomly chosen child's family. Express $E[W]$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

I got the answer $b/a$ by purely numeric calculation, but I really want to know how this answer is derived theoretically. Any hint or explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p_i$ is the percentage of families of $i$ children then the number of children is $\sum_{i=0}^n p_i i$. The probability that we select a particular child is $\frac{1}{\sum_{i=0}^n p_i i} $. Then the probability that we select a child belonging to a family of $k$ children is $\frac{kp_k}{\sum_{i=0}^n p_i i}.$ So 
$$E[W]=\sum_{k=0}^nk\frac{kp_k}{\sum_{i=0}^n p_i i}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k^2p_k}{\sum_{i=0}^n p_i i}=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^2p_k}{\sum_{i=0}^n p_i i}=\frac{b}{a}$$

because
$$a=\sum_{i=0}^nip_i \ \text{ and }\ b=\sum_{k=0}^nk^2p_k.$$

---

Note that $a$ and $b$ are not expectations on the first probability space. The solution of the paradox is that we operate in two different probability spaces.

Comment: Here is an explanation with full particulars, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Not a separate answer, but a follow-on comment that's a bit too large to fit into the comment box.

This is an instance of the so-called *inspection paradox*.  An interesting consequence of the paradox is that we could construct probability distributions where the expected number of children in a given family is finite, but if we select a child at random, the expected number of siblings of that child is infinite.

For instance, suppose that the probability that a given family has $k$ children is given by

$$
p_k = \frac{1}{\zeta(3)} \left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)
$$

where $\zeta(3) = 1/1^3+1/2^3+1/3^3+\cdots \doteq 1.2021$ is Apéry's constant.  Then the expected number of children in a family would be given by

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty kp_k
    = \frac{1}{\zeta(3)} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}
    = \frac{1}{\zeta(3)} \left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)
    \doteq 1.3684
$$

which seems perfectly ordinary.  However, if we go on to try to calculate the expected number of siblings for a randomly selected child, we run into an infinite second moment:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2p_k
    = \frac{1}{\zeta(3)} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k} > \infty
$$

Such are the travails of a heavy-tailed distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If $p_k$ proportion of families have $k$ children, for $k = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, m$, where $m$ is the maximum number of children in any family, this is equivalent to saying that the probability a randomly chosen family has $K$ children is $$\Pr[K = k] = p_k.$$  Thus, the expected value of $K$ is $$a = \operatorname{E}[K] = \sum_{k=0}^m k \Pr[K = k] = \sum_{k=0}^m k p_k,$$ and similarly, $$b = \operatorname{E}[K^2] = \sum_{k=0}^m k^2 p_k.$$

Now suppose there are $N$ families in our population.  Then $N p_k$ families have $k$ children, and the total number of children in the population is therefore $$n = \sum_{k=0}^m k N p_k = Na,$$ which is quite intuitive.  If we then choose one such child at random, the chance that they come from a family with $w$ children is equal to the number of children belonging to a family with $w$ children, divided by the total number of children $Na$; that is, $$\Pr[W = w] = \frac{w N p_w}{Na} = \frac{w p_w}{a}.$$  It follows that the expectation of $W$ is $$\operatorname{E}[W] = \sum_{w=0}^m w \Pr[W = w] = \sum_{w=0}^m \frac{w^2 p_w}{a} = \frac{1}{a} \sum_{w=0}^m w^2 p_w = \frac{b}{a},$$ as claimed.